# Trying to identify unwanted space underneath my footer when viewing on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, footer, spacing

I have 5 pages on my website. The "poetry" and "about us" page work fine on mobile, but the "index", "music", and "photos" page all have this weird space underneath the footer when viewed on mobile. I will post the css, along with the  3 pages that have a problem. The head section of each page is cut off to save space.

They may be lengthy but I am totally lost as to what is causing this problem, especially since they all share the same css classes. All 5 pages end with an empty "spacer" div to push the footer off of my content, and it has the same class on all 5 pages.

Everything looks fine on a desktop browser like Edge, Chrome and Firefox. I have checked on different size screens too.

```css
.header, .navBar, .pageTitle {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    
  }
font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #006464;
}

html, body, #container {
 min-height: 100vh;
}


footer {
    background-color: #bfd8d8;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

nav, h1, h2 {
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}



nav a:hover {
 background-color: #006400;
 
}

nav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
}

#container {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.centerContent {
 text-align: center;
}

#signUp {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: arial;
}


#welcomeFont {
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.currentNav {
 background-color: #006400;
}

.emailStyle {
 font-weight: bolder;
}

.footerSpacer {
 height:50px;
}

.header {
 color: white;
 background-color: #006400;
 padding: 20px;
}


.headerAnchor {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.navBar {
 background-color: #228B22;
 padding: 10px;

}

.pageTitle {
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px;
 background-color: #bfd8d8;
}


.poetryAuthor {
 color: white;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: arial;
 font-style: italic;
}

.poetryCaptions {
 margin-top: 50px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.resizeAbout{
 max-height: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
    
}

.resizeHome{
 max-height: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 margin-top: 50px;

}

.resizePhotos{
 max-height: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 
}

.table {
 background: #006464;
 
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-spacing: 10px;
 

}

.tableData {
 font-size: 19px;
 background: #bfd8d8;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 8px;
 
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <header>
   <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" href="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav class="navBar">
   <a class="currentNav" href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="music.html">Music</a>
   <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
   <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav> 
  
  <h2 class="pageTitle">
    Get the Full Effect!
  </h2>
  <div class="centerContent">
  <a href="image/homepage.jpg" target="blank"><img class="resizeHome" src="image/homepage.jpg" alt="Image of Daniel Adams"></a>
  <h3 id="welcomeFont">
    Welcome to the home of The Singular Effect!
  </h3> <br>
  
  <form>
    <span id="signUp">Sign up for our newsletter!</span> <br>
    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="Email Address">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="footerSpacer">
    
   </div>

  <footer>
   &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU. Contact me at <span class="emailStyle">christopher.hughes1@snhu.edu</span>
  </footer>
 
 </div>  

</body>

MUSIC:

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <header>
   <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" href="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav class="navBar">
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a class="currentNav" href="music.html">Music</a>
   <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
   <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav> 
   
  <h2 class="pageTitle">
    Music
  </h2>
  <div class="centerContent"> 
  <p class="poetryCaptions">The Day I Became Wind - Audio <br>
  <span class="poetryAuthor">by Daniel Adams</span></p>
  <audio controls="">
   <source src="audio/wind.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   This audio type isn't supported by your browser.
  </audio> 
  <br>
   
  <p class="poetryCaptions">The Day I Became Wind - Video <br>
  <span class="poetryAuthor">by Daniel Adams</span></p>
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6k32rSvoh0s"></iframe> 
  <br>

  <p class="poetryCaptions">Elven Mystics - Audio <br>
  <span class="poetryAuthor">by Daniel Adams</span></p>
  <audio controls="">
   <source src="audio/elvenmystics.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   This audio type isn't supported by your browser.
  </audio> 
  <br>
   
  <p class="poetryCaptions">Elvin Mystics - Video <br>
  <span class="poetryAuthor">by Daniel Adams</span></p>
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3n_JdFXLamA"></iframe> 
  <br>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footerSpacer">
    
   </div>

  <footer>
   &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU. Contact me at <span class="emailStyle">christopher.hughes1@snhu.edu</span>
  </footer> 
 </div>
  
</body>

PHOTOS:

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <header>
   <h1 class="header"><a class="headerAnchor" href="index.html">TheSingularEffect.Com</a></h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav class="navBar">
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="music.html">Music</a>
   <a class="currentNav" href="photos.html">Photos</a>
   <a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav> 
  
  <div class="centerContent">
  
   <h2 class="pageTitle">
     Photos
   </h2>

   <p class="poetryCaptions">Susquehanna River <br>
   <span class="poetryAuthor">by Daniel Adams</span></p>
   <a href="image/river.jpg" target="blank"><img class="resizePhotos" src="image/river.jpg" alt="Image of river"></a>
   <br>

   <p class="poetryCaptions">Grassy Plains - Island on the Susquehanna River <br> <span class="poetryAuthor">by Daniel Adams</span> </p>
   <a href="image/grass.jpg" target="blank"><img class="resizePhotos" src="image/grass.jpg" alt="Image of grassy plains"></a> 
   <br>
   <p>
    
   </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footerSpacer">
   
  </div>
   
  <footer>
   &copy; 2016, Chris Hughes - SNHU. Contact me at <span class="emailStyle">christopher.hughes1@snhu.edu</span>
  </footer>
 </div>
</body>

CSS:
```

Comment: Please edit it to be as short as possible. Remove a bit, test, repeat.

Comment: Also, I see no CSS..

Comment: the css is at the bottom of the snippet. I had this problem before when I posted separate snippets and was told by several people that I shouldn't post them separately but as one snippet. So I really don't know how to please everyone on here. But it is in there. I'll try to lop off the top part of the html pages because those are all the same.

Comment: Just fix where it says "CSS" and "HTML", like "CSS" is written on bottom

Comment: I will, however I had originally posted it with the CSS on the bottom of the HTML, and someone edited it in reverse.

Comment: And that edit was accepted!? Shame..

Comment: But the shorter you get the code here, the more people you can expect to read and try answering.

Comment: I didn't accept anything. I am still trying to figure out how everything works on here and it's quite confusing thus far.

Comment: Oh, OK. So you should read about it. There are plenty of articles. You'll need patience at first - keep strong! BTW, others can edit (I can) and someone with enough reputation (you have 14, for example) can accept the edit.

Comment: I also have tried to shorten code in the past however there are so many things going on with my code that I wanted to avoid cutting out something that may prove an essential clue as to what's causing my problem.

Comment: Simple: 1. remove a bit, 2. test. 3. Is the problem still there? If not, you found the piece that matters. If yes, return to step 1.

Comment: BTW, try clicking on all of the tabs in the snippet - some appear to be broken.

Comment: I have tested quite a bit on sublime 3, and that is why I brought it here. I cannot find the problem. I have been grinding on this for days with no results.

Comment: What do you mean? If you remove some and test, till the problem disappears, you'll know what piece caused. Alternatively, I can help more when I have time. You can contact me via http://AllDani.com